# Code returning false on equal compare?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, equals

Problem I currently have:

My server returns data back to the client, this includes a name. Now I want the client to grab this name and compare it. However for the past 3 hours I am stuck at this problem and I dont want to cheap fix around it.

My server returns a value and then a name, ex: random23454@NAMEHERE

I split the value using:

```
string[] values = returndata.Split('@');
```

And then I am doing:

```
if (textBox3.Text == values[1]) {
MessageBox.Show("equal");
}
```

However, the problem here is. I cant get it to be equal, I tried other methods but it just dont display equal.

What I have done:

Print textBox3.Text to a textbox and print values[1] to a other textbox and compared with my eye and mouse (Using invoke due to threading).

Used the .Trim() function
Using the .ToString() on values[1] (Just for the hell of it)
Assigned them both to a complete new string, trimmed them and compared them

Dragged the comparing outside the thread using:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            outside(name);
                        });
```

and perform the same check.

My code:

```
 string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                readData = "" + returndata;
                if (readData.Contains("@") && readData.Contains("random"))
                {


                    string[] values = returndata.Split('@');
                    string name = values[1].Trim();

                    if (textBox3.Text == name)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("true");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("false");
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                        {
                            outside(name);
                        });

                    }
```

What else can I do? I just dont understand that it is not equal..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to tell us about `inStream`. I *strongly* suspect that it's a byte array which contains the actual data and then a bunch of 0s... and you should be using `string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, dataRead)` - or using a `StreamReader` to start with.

Comment: Have you tried printing both values to console?

Comment: Try trimming the `TextBox` text. (`textBox3.Text.Trim()`)

Comment: I've printed both values to a messageBox and a textBox and they are both the same.

Comment: Now print the *length* of both values and tell me if those are the same please.

Comment: @selkathguy "values[1]" returns 10050 in lenght and the "textBox3.Text" returns 5.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with ASCII?? Have you tried utf-8?

Comment: @PaulG Please explain further?

Comment: @user2911924 Try `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);` instead of `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)`.

Comment: @user2911924 No problem, glad to help. I updated my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you're getting back from the server could be an array of bytes. Try converting the response to a `string` first before splitting. Also try printing the response (or the response's type) to console to see what you get before going any further.

Also make sure the `length` of each string is the same. Maybe give utf-8 a try instead of ASCII? Like so:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);
```

Comment: I've seen the output both in a messagebox and in a textbox, its just normal plain text.

Answer (score 0):

`string name = values[1].Trim();`

I think you want `values[2]` here. The way I read the documentation for [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the element at index 1 will be the (blank) separator indicator.

Comment: Gives me a error that its out of index, besides that it wouldnt display the plain value in a MessageBox or textBox either if this was the case. Thanks for your input anyways!